# how to return the value correctly from this javascript promise

Tags: javascript, promise, this

I have a class called block.js it should have a method called generatorHash(), the method should return the 'block' after it assigns  to it a new property which is its 'hash'

we need to assign the block to the this keyword and then after the promise gets resolved we should assign the new returned hash value to 'self(block).hash'

here's the code:

```js
/**
 * Import crypto-js/SHA256 library
 */
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

/**
 * Class with a constructor for block
 */
class Block {
  constructor(data) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.nonce = 144444;
    this.body = data;
    this.hash = this.self.hash;
  }

  /**
   * Step 1. Implement `generateHash()`
   * method that return the `self` block with the hash.
   *
   * Create a Promise that resolve with `self` after you create
   * the hash of the object and assigned to the hash property `self.hash = ...`
   */
  //
  generateHash() {
    let self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Implement your hash logic here
      this.self.hash = console.log(SHA256(JSON.stringify(self)).toString());
      resolve(self);
    });
  }
}
// Exporting the class Block to be reuse in other files
module.exports.Block = Block;
```

the error is:

```
this.hash = this.self.hash;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
    at new Block (/home/workspace/Project/block.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/workspace/Project/app.js:10:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: In `generateHash`, it should be `this.hash` or `self.hash` but not `this.self.hash`. Also, you should probably just assign `this.hash = null` in the constructor

Comment: @Phil all of them returned same error, the problem is in the promise

Comment: @Phil I actually need help retuning the value correctly from the promise

Comment: `this.self.hash = console.log(SHA256(JSON.stringify(self)).toString());` makes `this.self.hash==undefined`

Comment: Returning _what_ value?

Comment: @Phil the promise should resolve to 'self/block'

Comment: @TheBombSquad should I assign 'console.log(SHA256(JSON.stringify(self)).toString())' to self.hash only?

Comment: `console.log()` returns `undefined`

Comment: sorry im late.. wifi issues.. also.. take out the console.log COMPLETELY and just leave `this.self.hash=SHA256(JSON.stringify(self)).toString()`